# All combinations of a nested object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I have the following string

```
Hello, have a {good {night|day}|wonderful {evening|morning}} and {goodbye|bye}!
```

And I'm trying to generate all the combinations of the strings.
For example:
`Hello, have a good day and bye!`, `Hello, have a wonderful evening and goodbye!` etc.

Rules: `{one|two}` means write `one` on the first time and `two` on the second. As you can see these conditions can be nested any number of times.

I've parsed this to the following structure

```
[
 "Hello, have a ",
 {
  "or": [
   [
    "good ",
    {
     "or": [
      "night",
      "day"
     ]
    }
   ],
   [
    "wonderful ",
    {
     "or": [
      "evening",
      "morning"
     ]
    }
   ]
  ]
 },
 " and ",
 {
  "or": [
   "goodbye",
   "bye"
  ]
 },
 "!"
]
```

And now I can't figure out how to generate all the strings from this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the sentences directly when parsing, basically you just have to go through all the possibilities:

```js
function generateSentences(s) {
    const start = s.indexOf('{') + 1
    if (start == 0)
        return [s]
    for (let i = start, braces = 1;; i++)
        if (s[i] == '{')
            braces++
        else if (s[i] == '}')
            if (--braces == 0) {
                const options = generateOptions(s.substring(start, i)),
                      posts = generateSentences(s.substr(i + 1)),
                      pre = s.substring(0, start - 1)
                let sentences = []
                for (const option of options)
                    for (const post of posts)
                        sentences.push(pre + option + post)
                return sentences
            }
}
function generateOptions(options) {
    let braces = 0, start = 0, sentences = []
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        if (options[i] == '{')
            braces++
        else if (options[i] == '}')
            braces--
        else if (options[i] == '|' && braces == 0) {
            sentences = sentences.concat(generateSentences(options.substring(start, i)))
            start = i + 1
        }
    return sentences.concat(generateSentences(options.substring(start, options.length)))
}
console.log(generateSentences('Hello, have a {good {night|day}|wonderful {evening|morning}}!'))
console.log(generateSentences('hello, {|111|{!2!|@2@} 222|33 {@333@|444} 3333}! 555. {666|{777 {888|999}}} end...'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! however there is some bug. This is my test phrase `'hello, {|111|{!2!|@2@} 222|33 {@333@|444} 3333}! 555. {666|{777 {888|999}}} end...'`

Comment: @Londeren yes regex didn't work `{..}{..}` matched start to end instead of just the first part, corrected.

Comment: fantastic answer! You are my savior :)